# Fastest way to do peripheral clipping

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

In my Flash AS3 app, I am using

```
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

because graphically I want it to be workable out-of-the-box in all kinds of different mobile devices. It works a treat because it does a "best-fit" to the device's screen and simply "adds" black borders around it.

For example, in 4:3 screens it fills the whole screen nicely:
[image]

while in 16:9 screens I get black borders on the left and right:
[image]

Now here is the problem: when I am moving a display object "off-screen", I don't want it to be rendered inside those black borders.

The question is this: what is the fastest way to "clip" my app - considering I am targeting mobile devices? I have a feeling that a

```
stage.scrollRect
```

will blow things up performance-wise...

**EDIT** : I am using `<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollRect` is actually great and even makes your application perform better, *unless* you're using GPU composition (in which case it really degrades performance). So I'd suggest you trying it first.

But a good alternative solution (as crazy as it sounds) is to just have a huge rectangle with a hole on it on top of everything, as the last children of your stage. So suppose your stage is 640x480. You'd have a black rectangle on top of everything with dimensions of, say, 1640x1480, and with a hole of 640x480 pixels inside of it to let your content be visible. It's a cheap way to mimic a mask without forcing recomposition of the pixels inside that area.

Comment: I DO use <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>, so I suppose you recommend to go the rectangle way? And what would be best, to have the rectangle as a huge bitmap or use vector graphics instead?!

Comment: Yeah, if you use that then `scrollRect` is a no-go indeed. And a bitmap would *normally* be best, but this would be a big one, and can potentially use too much memory. I'd try a shape first, and if there's any hit to performance, use a smaller bitmap (e.g. 164x148 with a hole of 64x48) scaled up (10x in this case) with smoothing off. Rendering would be as quick, but memory use would be much smaller.